# why does Pow function return unexpected values..?

Tags: c++, pow, math.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i;
    i = 2;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", i,pow(i,2),pow(i,3));
    return 0;
}
```

/*
I expect the output to be 2,4,8.But the output shown is 2 0 1074790400.Can anyone explain me the reason please..?
*/

Comment: pow is double , so u need %f

Answer (score 5):

The return type of the overload of `pow` that you're using is `double`, so the behaviour of your code is undefined due to the invalid `printf` format specifiers.

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow

Comment: Consider using std::cout. You do not habe to care about the type you Luke to output.